# How do i properly remove letters from my string?

Tags: c#, xml, path, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get a path for my xml file. I have one string with the `.exe` file:

```
string exe_location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

and another string to contain the result:

```
string xml_location = exe_location.Remove(exe_location.Length, -11);
```

When I'm running the code, the debugger suddenly says: "*Count cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: count*"

I'm not sure how I managed to fail with this simple mission. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said from weirdev the "remove" function is the problem (the length is more than 11 and length -11 get to you a negative number). But if you want the path of your EXE file from exe assembly location you can use this code:

```
path = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: i canget the `.exe` by using only `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;` my problem is to get the path to the xml

Comment: @jjm Yes, the function "GetDirectoryName" give to you only the directory, without the name of exe. From "C:\your_folder\yourexe.exe" to "C:\you_folder". I thought this was the purpose for which you were using the "remove ".

Comment: oh. i didnt noticed that. you solved it. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of Remove() is a count of characters to remove. The first parameter is the index to begin removing. If you want to remove the last eleven characters you need.

```
Remove(exe_location.Length - 11, 11)
```

Comment: i changed `string xml_location = exe_location.Remove(exe_location.Length, -11);` to `string xml_location = exe_location.Remove(exe_location.Length - 11, 11);` and nothing changed. (i didnt get the error, but the number didnt change niether.